# Ternary operator concatenation

Tags: php

Why does

```
1 == 1 ? 'green' : 1 < 0 ? 'red' : 'yellow'
```

return `red` in PHP?

I come from Java and Javascript, where this expression returns `green`.

Simple fiddle to show it: https://jsfiddle.net/yt0e8t93/

Comment: Here's a PHP fiddle: https://eval.in/715786

Comment: thanks, I did not know existed PHP fiddle :) Now... why the result is red in PHP? O_o

Comment: The PHP gods are punishing you for using a nested ternary :)

Comment: Mhhhh why? :) I think this is the shorter way to create a condition like this. I should use if-elseif statement ? There is a reason why this dont works?

Comment: It is a bad, bad idea to use a ternary operator inside another one. It becomes too difficult to read. If statements would be far easier to decipher.

Comment: If you have to user ternary operators, at least use parentheses to group expressions. It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C, C++, Java, and Javascript will evaluate this as

`1 == 1 ? 'green' : (1 < 0 ? 'red' : 'yellow')`

due to the *associativity* of the ternary conditional operator being from right to left in all those languages. (This goes way back to before the `if` statement was even conceived).

But the PHP guys wanted to be different. In PHP, your expression is evaluated as

`(1 == 1 ? 'green' : 1 < 0) ? 'red' : 'yellow'`

This simplifies to `'green' ? 'red' : 'yellow'` which in turn is `'red'` as `'green'` is truthy. If you want it the old-fashioned way then use the parentheses as above.

Comment: It's no mistake that "eval in" is an anagram of "an evil".

Comment: Yes, with parentheses it works... sorry but i usually program in Java and Javascript. Thanks to php guys then :)